# Visual Studio: Remove class diagram from project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, class-diagram

I accidentally clicked "View Class Diagram" for one of my projects. How do I remove the .cd files from my project?

Update: You can't do this while debugging, but you can just right click on it and say "Exclude from Project". Thanks everyone!

Comment: Selecting and 'delete' doesn't work? You can't delete when you're debugging so you'll need to stop that first.

Comment: I must have only tried that while debugging. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to right click, exclude from project.

Comment: Oh boy I can't believe I didn't see that... I've been looking everywhere :)

Comment: It usually only takes once ;) At least you'll never forget it